# Multiple Regex Validation in Gallery rows based on Product Type

Tags: powerapps

I need to validate the textbox (code.Text) in the gallery based on regex + Product type (dropDownList)..

so I have a SharePoint list with the product type column and Regex associated with it.. sadly, IsMatch() cannot be dynamic.. Is there a way to read the Regex from the SharePoint list based on the selected Product type...

| Product type| Regex |
|:---- |:------:|
|Living Room  | IsMatch(code.Text,"^[a-zA-Z0-9.*%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$")|
|Kitchen Supplies  | IsMatch(code.Text,"^[a-zA-Z0-9.*%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]")|
and so on...

Here is a code I tried in Visible propery of the error message, where it lookup the SharePoint list to search for the selected product type and get the Regex associated to it but it didn't work...
Any idea on this please.. how to achieve validating based on multiple regex.

```
If (LookUp(RegEx,Title=lbl_Tag_Type_4.Text).regex,
            false,
            true
        )
```